# Error in i.p(...) : installation of package ... had non-zero exit status

Tags: java, r

I try to install the `RDRPOSTagger` package through `devtools`.

```
devtools::install_github("bnosac/RDRPOSTagger", build_vignettes = TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo bnosac/RDRPOSTagger@master
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install Rtools 3.5 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\X1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUD2iwv\remotes70c59a944c1\bnosac-RDRPOSTagger-af51e38/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  preparing 'RDRPOSTagger': (1.1s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'RDRPOSTagger_1.1.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/X1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'RDRPOSTagger' ...
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'RDRPOSTagger'
    finding HTML links ... done
    rdr_add_space_around_punctuations       html  
    rdr_available_models                    html  
    rdr_model                               html  
    rdr_pos                                 html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/X1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RDRPOSTagger'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/X1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUD2iwv/file70c8917649/RDRPOSTagger_1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

Java version on my CPU: java 10.0.2 64 bit

I try to use the `qdap` package which also needs `rJava` and this works just fine.

Comment: From the the full error message, it seems that `rJava` is the culprit. I would try getting that working first.

Comment: Java must be working. However, if I load it I get this message: 'library(rJava) Warning message: package ‘rJava’ was built under R Version 3.5.2.' This doesn't change if I reinstall the package.

Comment: Install a new version of R. You seem to have R below 3.5.2. Could you post your `sessionInfo`?

Comment: See my edits on the post.

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded

This package is not loaded because JAVA_HOME is not set.

It can be done by first installing depending on your R (32 bit or 64 bit), Java 32 bit or 64 bit.

Download java from here: https://www.java.com/en/download/

Using this find JAVA_HOME address:

```
find.java <- function() {
        for (root in c("HLM", "HCU")) for (key in c("Software\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment", 
            "Software\\JavaSoft\\Java Development Kit")) {
            hive <- try(utils::readRegistry(key, root, 2), 
              silent = TRUE)
            if (!inherits(hive, "try-error")) 
              return(hive)
        }
        hive
    }
```

Load find.java and you will find the address for JAVA_HOME. Enter that address here:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Your\\Java\\Directory')
library(rJava)
```

That should load the package `rJava`.

ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'

This error is maybe because you have downloaded both version of R (32 bit and 64 bit) and devtools tries to build for both of them.

You can use this:

```
devtools::install_github("mne-tools/mne-r", INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))
```

I was also getting the similar type of error and after searching through I came across this solutions which worked for me.